# wp_mail() won't send more than two consecutive messages on server or testing locally through mailtrap.io

Tags: wordpress, email

I'm running into a weird issue where I can't send more than two consecutive messages through wp_mail(). If I send three emails only two will be sent.

This happens regardless of whether I am running the code on the hosted site or on my local development setup through mailtrap.io.

I have installed a fresh theme and simplified the code down to the below for testing purposes, and still the issue persists.

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', function($phpmailer){
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host     = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpmailer->Port     = 2525;
    $phpmailer->Username = '************';
    $phpmailer->Password = '************';
} );


add_action('init', function(){


    $email_headers = [
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        'From: Company ABC <example@site.test>'
    ];

    wp_mail('recipient@site.test', 'Test Subject 1', "<html><body>Test Message 1</body></html>", $email_headers);
    wp_mail('recipient@site.test', 'Test Subject 2', "<html><body>Test Message 2</body></html>", $email_headers);
    wp_mail('recipient@site.test', 'Test Subject 3', "<html><body>Test Message 3</body></html>", $email_headers);
    wp_mail('recipient@site.test', 'Test Subject 4', "<html><body>Test Message 4</body></html>", $email_headers);

});
```

Comment: Are you using the free version of Mailtrap.io?

Comment: @BA_Webimax Yes I am

Comment: You should review the terms of the free plan, you are rate limited to only 2 emails every 10 seconds with the free tier. https://mailtrap.io/pricing

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'm guessing Godaddy has a similar limit. I've setup mailhog and the messages are being received properly.